# Download file in JSP with AJAX

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a simple JSP page, which contains 2 buttons: View and Export. When View button is clicked I will fetch data from DB, keep a copy into session and write an HTML code into a label with the data. Later when user clicks Export I want to generate an excel file in the server(with the data from session) and download it to clientside.

Excel file is successfully created at serverside. I am using an AJAX request from clientside to download Excel file from server.

JSP code:

```
 try{                           

                    String filepath=ExportToExcel(session.getAttribute("InvestmentDetails"));

                    //Setting file to download
                    response.setContentType( "application/x-download");

                    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"SIPInvestment_531.xls\"");                                                                             
                    response.setStatus(200);
                    InputStream in = null;
                    ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();                        

                    try {                            
                        File filetodownload=new File(filepath);
                        response.setContentLength(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(filetodownload.length())));                                
                        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filetodownload));                            
                        int ch;
                        while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                            outs.print((char) ch);
                        }
                    }
                    finally {
                        if (in != null) in.close(); 
                    }
                    outs.flush();
                    outs.close();                                                

                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    str=ex.getMessage();                                          
                }
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {


                    }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","/SIP/rptClientInvestmentDetails.jsp?requesttype=export",false);
            xmlhttp.send();
```

The request reaches on JSP page. And without any exception it writes to response outputstream. But no download is pop up from browser. What can be the problem?

Comment: You don't get an exception stating you've already starting writing to the response because you try writing to the response again in inappropriate Java code embedded in the JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax should be used for meta-languages, not for binary files.

A simple

```
 <a href="/SIP/rptClientInvestmentDetails.jsp?requesttype=export"
    target="_blank">Export</a>
```

is all you need.

If you make sure you said the `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment` you should drop the target-attribute as BalusC suggested.

Comment: Note that the `target` attribute is not necessary here. It may even be disturbing as it leaves the enduser with a completely blank tab because this type of download content type forces a *Save as* dialogue.

Comment: JavaScript has due to obvious security reasons no facilities to force a *Save As* dialogue with independently retrieved/generated content.

Comment: @Vivek it is "usable", but it is not a good idea. if you like to spend your whole live for a project called "excel for javascript", but its more intelligent to eat spaghetti using the color yellow.

Comment: @BalusC some of my clients like to have the error-message in a seperate window. i dont know why. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use location.href="Provide the java class function name".This will transfer the control from jsp to java function without using the ajax call

Comment: Please list the Frameworks that are required for such an effect.